# How to make user.html.twig template for two different pages (users)?

Tags: users, 8, theming

I want to make `user.html.twig` template for user ID1 is not such as to all other users. How to?

I tried this code in `MYTHEME.theme` file:

```
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_page_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  if ($user = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('users')) {
    // For make files, like:
    // page--user--[id].html.twig
    $suggestions[] = 'page__user__' . $user->uid();
  }
}
```

But template `page--user--1.html.twig` or `page--user--%.html.twig` don't work. Cache is clear.

Comment: You have a typo in userS. Also you should rather check route name instead of parameters.

Comment: If ``user`` in ``\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter()`` I see white screen without any errors.

Comment: what is in the error.log?

Comment: @4k4 where is error.log place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Platon, you appear to be mixing up the template for the user itself (`user.html.twig`) and the overall page template (`page.html.twig`).

If you want to override the user template then you need to implement [hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK/8) where "HOOK" is "user" which is the theme hook you are overriding.

Here is an example of what that code would look like if you were using Bartik (but of course in practice you should be using your own subtheme rather than hacking core):

```
function bartik_theme_suggestions_user_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $suggestions[] =  'user__' . $variables['elements']['#user']->id();
  return $suggestions;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In "themename.theme" file use below template suggestion hook

```
function themename_theme_suggestions_user_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
    if($currentUserID == 10){
        $suggestions[] =  'user__info';
    }
    elseif($currentUserID == 12){
        $suggestions[] =  'user__profile';
    }
  return $suggestions;
}
```

and create two new files "user--info.html.twig" and "user--profile.html.twig" under 'themename/templates/page/' directory and copy the content of "user.html.twig" and paste into it